# who/w commands not working in docker image from ubuntu:22.04 (missing /var/run/utmp file)

Tags: command-line, 22.04, docker

I created a docker container from this Dockerfile (I removed not relevant lines):

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Etc/UTC

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server && apt-get autoremove -

...
```

I've notice that when using `who` or `w` while a user is connected to the container with SSH, I get empty results. As I understand these files simply read the content of the file `/var/run/utmp`, this file is missing from the container

```
ls /var/run/utmp
ls: cannot access '/var/run/utmp': No such file or directory
```

If I add this file manually, the `who` command works as expected.
But I guess it's a bad solution.

However, if I change the ubuntu version to 20.04 (ubuntu:20.04), the file is there:

```
ls -la /var/run/utmp 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 0 Dec 11 02:14 /var/run/utmp
```

And `who` command is working.

Why this is not working in version 22.04? Is there a specific package that I need to install?

Comment: I suppose whoever made the 22.04 image removed `/var/run/utmp` either intentionally or by making the image start up in a non-standard way. `man utmp` mentions that the file is created by the `init` process, i.e. right after boot, and must always exist on a Linux system. There would be no harm in you creating it in your Dockerfile.